# Best way to add an existing repo to git to a different branch behind proxy

Tags: github, proxy, branch, production

There is a website in production.
I want to push the files in Git.

I think the client did copy all the files from his computer to the server using ftp.
I think he pushed his git perso files, cause I can see a `.git` folder in live.

I tried "`git status`" on the live server, It returns a list of files.

I did:

```
git remote show origin
->error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing....
```

The live site use a proxy.

What's the best way to push the current live site to Github?

I want to create a new branch in github and then, on the server, I want to do:

```
$ git remote add origin http....
$ git push -u origin newbranch
```

Do you think there is a way to break the live site?
I have a copy of this website but I don't want to break the current website.

What do you recommend?
First create a backup? Then do the Github thing?

Answer (score 0):

One way to break the live site is if you make an unintended git pull, once you managed to push it to GitHub!

Plus you would need to fiddle with the proxy in order to access to GitHub, all on the production platform.

I would really recommend *having* nothing on the production server except what is strictly needed to *run* the web site.
So not git.

Use rsynch/copy mechanism to publish on prod, but keep a git repo on another machine, one which can contact easily Github, and push from *there* (not from prod)

Comment: I don't do a git push, I won't break the live site.
It's a magento website. If the client made some changes in live from backend, or even If he uploads a new file I won't be able to commit these changes...

Comment: @Sandy you won't be able to commit, unless you rsync them back to a machine with a git repo, in which git will detect the change.